# Is there a function to divide a n dimensional tensor with an n-1 dimensional tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am not sure how to word this question properly so I will show some examples to describe the desired behaviour.

I'm looking to divide a tensor in this specific way.

1. Divide a vector by 1 scalar, for example `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` divided by 2 = `[0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]`
2. Divide a matrix by 2 scalars, for example `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]` by `[2, 4]` = `[[0.5, 1, 1.5], [0.5, 0.75, 1]]`
3. Divide a 3 dimensional tensor by a 2 dimensional tensor, for example `[[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]], [[4,5,6], [7,8,9]], [[9,8,6], [1,2,3]]]` divided by `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` = `[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 1.5, 2]], [[4/3,5/3,2], [7/4,2,9/4]], [[9/5,8/5,6/5], [1/6,2/6,3/6]]]`
4. Divide a N dimensional tensor by a N-1 dimensional tensor...

I'm looking for a pytorch way to do this.

Comment: So really you just intend to treat the data as an N-dimensional array, broadcasting along one axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the dimensions of the N-1 dimensional tensor to make it [broadcastable](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html) with the N-dimensional tensor.

```py
tensor_a / tensor_b.unsqueeze(-1)
```

This generalizes, even when the denominator is a scalar. The `-1` dimension means the last dimension. This follows from python indexing rules, in which `sequence[-1]` gives you the last element of the sequence.

```py
a = torch.as_tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = torch.as_tensor(2)
a / b.unsqueeze(-1)
# tensor([0.5000, 1.0000, 1.5000, 2.0000, 2.5000])

a = torch.as_tensor([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
b = torch.as_tensor([2, 4])
a / b.unsqueeze(-1) 
# tensor([[0.5000, 1.0000, 1.5000],
#         [0.5000, 0.7500, 1.0000]])

a = torch.as_tensor([[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]], [[4,5,6], [7,8,9]], [[9,8,6], [1,2,3]]])
b = torch.as_tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
a / b.unsqueeze(-1) 
# tensor([[[1.0000, 2.0000, 3.0000],
#          [1.0000, 1.5000, 2.0000]],
#
#         [[1.3333, 1.6667, 2.0000],
#          [1.7500, 2.0000, 2.2500]],
#
#         [[1.8000, 1.6000, 1.2000],
#         [0.1667, 0.3333, 0.5000]]])
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the behavior of unsqueeze(-1) as the pytorch documentation doesnt seem to include -1 in their explanation. But this solution solved my problem!

https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html

Comment: Great! I updated my answer. `-1` means the last dimension.